# Facial location coordinates for DSC-WX500

Tags: camera, sony

The liveview data for this camera does not return a frame that includes facial location(s).  Is there a way, using the remote camera API for this camera, to collect the facial location data that appears on the LCD screen but not in the liveview data?  For example, can EXIF tags be configured in the JPG image header that would include facial locations?  Any other ways to do convey the facial location data with the remote camera API?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to extract the facial location data.  We will keep this in mind for future products.